# Process Synchronization on mac os

Tags: macos

Can someone explain me how MAC OS X handles  process  synchronization?
also if you can share a a good link where u could find information about
thanks.
I already looked on the internet but did n find much information about.

Comment: Q: Could you be more specific?  For example, do you want to write some code that does synchronization? Do you want to know what synchronization APIs the MacOS/BSD kernel offers?  Do you want to better understand the MacOS/BSD kernel scheduler?  Perhaps this link might help: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/synchronization/synchronization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000905-CH218-BEHJDFCA

Comment: Yes, i have a presentation, and i have to explain how mac os x handles process synchronization .What techniques does it uses. For example linux was a nonpreemptive kernel, meaning that a process running in kernel mode could not be preempted, even if a higher-priority process became available, now linux is fully preemptive, and provides spinlocks and semaphores. Im trying to find this kind of information but for mac os x